# Stack (Data structure) implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

So I'm just starting to learn about data structures through a course on Coursera and I learned that it's possible to create a stack data structure by using an array. I was just wondering if what I have written is what a stack is supposed to do.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 10000;

class Stack {
    public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack();
        void push(int n);
        void pop();
        int top();
        bool isEmpty() const;
        void print() const;
    private:
        int* array [MAX_SIZE];
        int curNum;
};

Stack::Stack() {
    curNum = 0;
}

Stack::~Stack() {
    for (int i = 0; i < curNum; ++i) 
        delete array[i];
}

void Stack::push(int n) {
    if (curNum >= MAX_SIZE) {
        cout << "reached maximum capacity...can't add an element\n";
        return;
    }
    array[curNum] = new int(n);
    curNum++;
}

void Stack::pop() {
    delete array[curNum];
    curNum--;
}

int Stack::top() {
    return *array[curNum];
}

void Stack::print() const{
    for (int i = 0; i < curNum; ++i) 
        cout << *array[i] << endl;
}

bool Stack::isEmpty() const{
    return curNum == 0;
}

int main () {
    Stack stack;
    stack.push(5);
    stack.print();
    stack.pop();
}
```

Also, I see that a lot of people don't use dynamic memory allocation for this kind of task. Is there a reason why? It seems like specifying a size for the array at compile time might lead to insufficient memory or over-allocating memory to me

Comment: Write a test app that pushes things onto the stack and then pops them back off. Does it work properly? We're not code testers.

Comment: It's funny you mention insufficient memory or over-allocating memory considering an array of 10000 int pointers is likely 80 KB on the stack plus 40 KB + overhead of dynamic allocation (if all used), while an array of 10000 ints is likely 40 KB on the stack and that's all.

Comment: @chris Oh you're right...but what if you had a bunch of objects of a class instead of regular ints?

Comment: @KenWhite It seems to work but I'm just always paranoid about these things lol...in school I always tend to miss 1 or 2 test cases even though I tested my code multiple times

Comment: If the class is big enough, it might be worth dynamically allocating its objects, but that case doesn't come up all too often. It's also possible to have a single big chunk of dynamic memory containing the objects instead of 10000 small chunks all separate from each other killing spatial locality (that is, iterating through needs to go fetch different parts of memory for each element). The single chunk approach would be comparable to a vector-backed stack, which is actually possible with `std::stack`, though not quite the default.

Comment: @chris ok this is something that I kind of don't understand...does it matter if there is a contiguous block of memory containing the objects vs having it separate? Is that kinda like arrays vs linked lists? Thanks

Comment: @HowardWang -- *It seems like specifying a size for the array at compile time might lead to insufficient memory or over-allocating memory to me* -- That's why the "real" stack class, `std::stack` uses a `std::deque` internally.  Your implementation oddly has an array of pointers, which doesn't make sense.  Maybe you should first use a dynamic array/deque and have your stack class use that instead?

Comment: So write your test to push and pop varying numbers of values and see if they're all correct (write a loop to push 10 random values and then pop the last 5 and see if they're correct, etc.). Again, we're not a code testing service. When you get further along, you'll probably learn about unit testing. (Your question about memory allocation is a totally separate question, BTW, and should be posted as such.)

Comment: @HowardWang, Yes, it's one main difference between arrays and linked lists. With one big chunk, you have the overhead of managing that single chunk (e.g., "how big is this chunk?") and everything is right next to each other, so the hardware can fetch the entire thing at once. With individual allocations, you have the overhead of managing each one and unless you go out of your way, the chunks are all over the place. There are other advantages and disadvantages of each, of course; this is just in regard to memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is one way to implement a stack. The important thing that defines a stack is LIFO (last in, first out). So as long as you are only adding to and removing from the top, then that is a stack. Think of it as a stack of dishes; if 10 dishes are put one by one into a stack, and then one by one removed from said stack, the first dish put on will also be the last dish removed. You can't remove a dish that's not at the top, as it is covered by all the dishes above it. The same is true with a stack data structure.

So your implementation is indeed a stack.

Answer (score 0):

The stack we use when we want something in reverse order and stack also takes constant time means O(1) time to push and pop means to remove or to add it will work much faster

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).